# PHP Sleep function causes double request after 10 minutes

Tags: php, zend-framework, sleep

i am using zend framework 1.12. Recently I found a bug that causes new request attempt when placing `sleep(540);`.

It will re request again from starting point before current execution finished.

What's the solution for this issue?

This issue also arises in simple php script.

**NOTE** :  Working fine in my windows localhost(wamp) but found issue on linux with zend server

Example :

```
<?php
 error_reporting(1);
    $con = mysql_connect('server_name','username','password');
    mysql_select_db('test11',$con);
    if(isset($_POST['a'])) {
       $sql = "insert into test(name,data) values ('".$_POST['a']."','".$_POST['b']."') "; 
        mysql_query($sql);
  sleep(600);
  echo "sdfsfsf";
    }
?>

<html>
    <body>
        <form method="post" name="frm" id ="frm">
            <input type="text" name="a" id="a">
            <input type="text" name="b" id="b">
            <input type="submit" name="btnsubmit" id="btnsubmit" value="Submit">        
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Updated**

Actually we have php script which do some calculation after fetching rows from db having larger data which takes more than 10 minutes to complete whole process
, but after 4-5 minutes same duplicate post request attempt with same data was made. So to find this issue we made sample php script and put sleep after db operation and found the same issue.

Comment: Add some code example if not the real code that demonstrates this situation, we are not clairvoyant

Comment: @RiggsFolly question updated

Comment: check [max_execution_time](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)

Comment: @cske max_execution_time is 3600

Comment: Move sleep outside the if statement. Why you use it in first place anyway?

Comment: @Stanimir question updated

Comment: any update on this. I have the same problem. I am using zend framework on linux. I am using sleep to delay the api response. But when i use sleep the function is executed twice. Please help me with this? I have checked max_execution_time in php.ini, the value is too high.